# How can I understand this recursion example in Scala?

Tags: scala, recursion

I have the following method in Scala which uses recursion:

```
def foldLeft[Result](initial:Result, op:(Result, Elem) => Result) : Result = {
   if (isEmpty)
     initial
   else
    tail.foldLeft(op(initial,head), op)
```

However I don't understand how the recursion in the last line works.
It seems a bit convoluted for me because the the foldLeft is called on the tail of an list before anything else is done.
How do the recursion levels look like here?

Can somebody explain how exactly this works?

Comment: It is not really at all recursive but more about method dispatch. Basically `foldLeft` of a non empty list is the the `foldLeft` of the tail where the new accumulator is the result of `op` called with the head and the current accumulator. - I personally prefer to use the function way of defining `foldLeft` since the _(tail)_ recursion is easier to see and explain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the foldLeft is called on the tail of an list before anything else is done".  Calling `tail.foldLeft` is the last thing done (in the case of a non-empty list.

Scala (like most languages in wide use today) uses a *strict* strategy for evaluating a function application (Haskell is probably the most widely used language which uses a non-strict strategy, and Scala is likely the most widely used language which directly supports opting out of the strict strategy).  This means that when applying a function, the arguments are fully evaluated and then passed to the function.

It is thus absolutely correct to imagine the compiler translating the code in the question to the equivalent in Scala:

```
if (isEmpty) {
  initial
} else {
  val _arg1 = op(initial, head)
  tail.foldLeft(_arg1, op)
}
```

For example

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).foldLeft(0, _ + _)
```

would evaluate into (because `List(1, 2, 3, 4)` is nonempty)

```
List(2, 3, 4).foldLeft(1, _ + _)
```

and then into (since `List(2, 3, 4)` is nonempty)

```
List(3, 4).foldLeft(3, _ + _)
```

and then into (since `List(3, 4)` is nonempty)

```
List(4).foldLeft(6, _ + _)
```

and then into (since `List(4)` is nonempty; and assuming that you're using `Nil` to represent the empty list)

```
Nil.foldLeft(10, _ + _)
```

and then into (since `Nil` is empty)

```
10
```